# I am trying to combine 3 tables for to get a distinct combination as below

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT TYPE_DETAILS(a.column1,c.column2,c.column3) BULK COLLECT INTO OUT_DETAILS
FROM TABLE1 a
INNER JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.column2 = b.column2
INNER JOIN TABLE3 c ON a.column3 = c.column3;
```

I only want combinations for distinct values of a.column1 . If I apply distinct as below i am getting error

```
SELECT TYPE_DETAILS(DISTINCT a.column1,c.column2,c.column3) BULK COLLECT INTO OUT_DETAILS
FROM TABLE1 a
INNER JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.column2 = b.column2
INNER JOIN TABLE3 c ON a.column3 = c.column3;
```

Comment: cant use IN as values returned will be more than 1000

Comment: Just for your knowledge, if you have tuple (mtiple values) in left side of the IN and tuples in the IN, you can use as many values as you want (no limit of 1000) e.g. `(col1, col2) IN ((val101,val102),(val201,val202).....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use sub-query:

```
SELECT TYPE_DETAILS(column1,column2,column3) 
   BULK COLLECT INTO OUT_DETAILS FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT a.column1,c.column2,c.column3
FROM TABLE1 a
INNER JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.column2 = b.column2
INNER JOIN TABLE3 c ON a.column3 = c.column3);
```